# Xcode 6.0.1, Swift, UIKit, CoreGraphics missing

Tags: xcode, swift, uikit, core-graphics

**To make it short:**

Do never ever give a project a frameworks name! I called my project "CoreGraphics".

**Original question:**

I cant use CoreGraphics in a newly created **simple** Single View Application

- I start **Xcode 6.0.1** (6A317)
- New Project: Single View Application: Swift
- New File: Cocoa Touch Class "CustomView" of type `UIView`
- I uncomment the template for `drawRect(rect: CGRect) {}`

Compiler Error: **Use of undeclared type 'CGRect'.**

- `import UIKit` is in place
- I tried to add CoreGraphics to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
- I already restarted Xcode (and my Mac)

**Update**

- I installed **Xcode 6.1** (6A1046a) opened and recreated my simple project.

Same issue: Compiler Error: Use of undeclared type 'CGRect'.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: can't reproduce on my Mac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't name your Project "CoreGraphics"

Answer (score 3):

Guys you WON'T believe this. **Do never ever give a project a frameworks name!** I called my project "CoreGraphics". This caused the compiler error. Its reproducable. Issue closed.