# getting error while using drawRect of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, ios9.3

getting error " Use of undeclared type CGRect" when using drawRect of UIView.
attached screenshot .

```
override   func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
  UIColor.greenColor().setFill();
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEG2m.png)

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399956/xcode-6-0-1-swift-uikit-coregraphics-missing

Comment: Don't name your project with the same name as a framework.